# Logistic Regression with AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: logistic-regression

I have been doing logistic regression and it throws this error which I have no idea how to resolve. If anybody could help with it I will be very grateful. Link to the code is
https://www.kaggle.com/bhavinmoriya/logistic-reg
Thanks a lot.

Comment: ```LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')``` solves the problem.

Comment: Credit to the solution goes to, https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/275869#1531974